# How is that I can not investigate part of HTML in browser inspector?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have here this seating layout: https://www.jegy.hu/program/kabare-121948/713631

If I investigate one available seat in Chrome, inspector does not show coordinates of the div for that particular seat. Why? Maybe because seat coordinates loaded with Javascipt later, directly to DOM?

Is it a way to extract part of the HTML if they are loaded via Javascipt to DOM?

[image]

Comment: There is a input hidden one on each seat. Example: '<input type="hidden" class="sector" id="sector_1" data-sectorid="1" data-isfree="0" data-inbasket="0" data-type="0" data-name="Erkély" data-sumprice="0">'

Comment: Yes, but that input represents a whole section of seats. I would expect to see float numbers X, Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT.

Comment: No, every input target a particular ID, no need to have coordinates

Comment: I thought I will find HTML `<rect>` elements, isn't this used behind the veil? If not what else represents a seat? https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_rect.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not really investigate one available seat, at least not as you would expect.

The first thing is that the website lays a `<div>` over the actual image, that looks like it is used to collect all user interaction (events) with the image (e.g. scrolling, navigating). This is the div you have selected in your screenshot. You can go ahead and just delete it.

Then you'll notice that there are `<canvas>` elements that create a 4x4 grid of tiles. The actual seats are painted into these canvas elements. They are not even real DOM objects.

But there are elements you can investigate: the `<text>`s like "JOBB KARZAT". Just search for that string in the DOM and you'll find some interesting elements.

Comment: Do you think rendering on canvas happens on server or client side?

Comment: Rendering into the canvas has to happen on client side, you can find more about it at the [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) MDN article. It is possible that the server compiles all paints and the client just applies them, but that is pure speculation. But then the 4x4 grid of tiles smells like a framework being used that does all the heavy lifting, so everything is possible.